# Suitable Wording for An Experiment

Tags: dataset, simulation

My question is related to finding a suitable word to demonstrate the following and I wonder if someone could provide me with a proper suggestion!

In statistics, if we use a real data set for the Monte Carlo simulation, what should we call this experiment? I definitely do not want to use the word [simulation] and would like it would be clear that real data has been used. How about one of the following?
[1.] empirical example
[2.] illustration using actual data

Thank you.

Comment: I think either one of these phrasings would be adequate, but it's quite subjective and "to the taste" of the writer and reader

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Comment: I wouldn't call this Monte Carlo. Instead, I would explicitly write that there are m 
real experiments has been performed.